# UINavigationBar that changes transparency when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement `UINavigationBar` that changes its transparency when scrolling `UITableView`. At the beginning, the navigation bar should have transparent background, so the content below it should be visible (there will be an image displayed, for the example I am using solid color):

[image: Example 1]

When user scrolls table view, transparency should be replaced with solid color:

[image: Example 2]

Table view will contain section headers, that should act like when using non-translucent navigation bar. The header views should "stick" to navigation bar once they "touch" it from the bottom:

[image: Example 3]

I have no luck with trying to implement this flow in iOS app.

For the initial state, I am setting `UINavigationBar` `translucent` property to `YES`, and both `backgroundColor` and `barTintColor` to clear color, which gives me what I want.

Then, when user scrolls table view, I am updating the `backgroundColor` and `barTintColor` to a color with given alpha component, computed basing on current scroll offset. I am using `scrollViewDidScroll:` from `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to do so. However, it changes only the background of navigation bar, leaving status bar background transparent, which is not what I want.

I can't find another way of making `UINavigationBar` transparent without setting `translucent` property to `YES`. Unfortunately, this changes how the section headers acts when scrolling. As navigation bar is translucent, section header views hides below it when they should "stick" to the bar like on third screenshot above.

I would appreciate any help and hints how to achieve navigation bar that acts like described or similar in Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: Hey check [LTNavigationbar](https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationbar) which might be helpful.

Comment: Been looking for that find @PareshNavadiya Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a reference to the view above the tableView and that you don't want to interact anything in it:

```
var overlayView:UIView!
var offsetDenominator:CGFloat!
let TARGER_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let navCtrl = self.navigationController {
        self.offsetDenominator = headerView.frame.size.height - navCtrl.navigationBar.frame.height

        let targetCIColor = CIColor(CGColor: self.TARGER_COLOR.CGColor)
        let overlayColor = UIColor(red: targetCIColor.red, green: targetCIColor.green, blue: targetCIColor.blue, alpha: 0.0)

        self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.headerView.frame)
        self.overlayView.backgroundColor = overlayColor

        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)
    }

...

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let navCtrl = self.navigationController, let breakpoint = offsetDenominator {
        let alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y / breakpoint

        if alpha >= 1.0  {
            navCtrl.navigationBar.backgroundColor = self.TARGER_COLOR
        } else {
            let targetCIColor = CIColor(CGColor: self.TARGER_COLOR.CGColor)
            let overlayColor = UIColor(red: targetCIColor.red, green: targetCIColor.green, blue: targetCIColor.blue, alpha: alpha)

            self.overlayView.backgroundColor = overlayColor
            navCtrl.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    self.setNavbarTransculent()
}

private func setNavbarTransculent() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let denominator: CGFloat = 50 //your offset treshold
    let alpha = min(1, scrollView.contentOffset.y / denominator)
    self.setNavbar(backgroundColorAlpha: alpha)
}

private func setNavbar(backgroundColorAlpha alpha: CGFloat) {
    let newColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: alpha) //your color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = newColor
    UIApplication.shared.statusView?.backgroundColor = newColor
}

extension UIApplication {
    var statusView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread 1: "App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead."

Answer (score -4):

**Swift3**

```
var navAlpha = // Your appropriate calculation   
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(navAlpha)
```